# NpgSQL Throwing Exception

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql, pgadmin-4

Im currently working on a .Net application that has a PostgreSQL backend. Im using NpgSQL to connect the two. When I try to do simple data retrieval, NpgSQL returns the following error:

> 42601: syntax error at or near "get_all_reviews"

PostgreSQL Function being called:

```
create or replace function public.get_all_reviews()
    returns TABLE(review_text text, review_sentiment integer) as $$
begin
    return query select rec.review_text, rec.review_sentiment from reviews as rec;     
end;
$$ language plpgsql;

ALTER FUNCTION public.get_all_reviews()
    OWNER TO postgres;
```

C#/NpgSQL:

```
 public List<Review> GetReviews()
        {
            var reviews = new List<Review>();
            var postgresqlConnection = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=localhost;Port=5432;User Id=user;Password=password;Database=db;");
            postgresqlConnection.Open();

            var command = new NpgsqlCommand("get_all_reviews", postgresqlConnection);
            try
            {
                var dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();

                ...do stuff

                postgresqlConnection.Close();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }           

            return reviews;
        }
```

The exception occurs on `command.ExecuteReader()`. However, if I run the following query in pgAdmin4, I get the desired results from the aforementioned function:

```
select get_all_reviews()
```

Comment: Did you perhaps try `var command = new NpgsqlCommand("select get_all_reviews()", postgresqlConnection);`?

Comment: I just tried it and it works now. In hindsight I now understand why; however, at the time, I didnt know the select keyword needed to be included in the command as well. Thank you!

Comment: How were you running it in your query tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL that you successfully executed was:

```
select get_all_reviews()
```

When you ran it from C# though, you ran different SQL:

```
get_all_reviews
```

As such, the solution is to use the working SQL in C# as well:

```
var command = new NpgsqlCommand("select get_all_reviews()", postgresqlConnection);
```

*This is necessary, since the FUNCTION returns a TABLE, which you are SELECTing from.*

Comment: FYI if you set [CommandType.StoredProcedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.commandtype?view=netframework-4.8) on the command, you can provide simply the name and Npgsql will generate the select (and parentheses). Note there's no particular advantage in doing so, see [these docs for more details](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/basic-usage.html).